# multiple JComboBox listeners

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I am new to JComboBox

I have 4 JComboBoxes: specialite, etudiant, annee, and semestre.

I need to get the selected item from the 4 of them each time I change the selected item and add the result to the ScrollPane (groupe des matieres ouvertes)

[image: Project Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the below JComboBox basic example given by Java. Use getSelectedItem() of JComboBox in actionPerformed() method of each combo box whenever an item got selected in it.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        updateScrollpane(petName); // Update your scrollpane
}
```

Do the same thing for all of your 4 dropdowns and update the scrollpane

Comment: I thaught that i need item listener to check what item is selected